# How can I track and store the email open time for subscribers in my Salesforce Marketing Cloud data extension using Ampscript?

Tags: salesforce, email-templates, salesforce-marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to use Ampscript to record the email open time of subscribers and store it in a data extension in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

I would like to save the email open time of an subscriber to my marketing cloud data extension to send some other message.

Comment: AMPscript is a server-side language and is only evaluated/compiled at send time.  The data you're seeking is already recorded in the _Open data view: https://dbdiagram.io/d/5ff259ed80d742080a34e3c3